# Separator lines don't show up under custom tableView cells despite enabling it in Attributes inspector

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I went to Attributes inspector of my TableView and added a "single line" separator as follows:

[image]

The separator seems to be appearing in the Storyboard tableView

However, when I run the app:
[image: No lines]

This was done via Storyboard so not sure what else information is needed.
Just incase I've uploaded it to Github using xcode source control:

https://github.com/bigmit2011/TableView-TableView

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See the red arrow at the upper left of the canvas? That tells you you're in serious trouble. Do not attempt to run your app until you've made it go away.

Comment: @matt Ah. Thank you. I actually just eradicated of all constraints, so the red arrows have disappeared. However,even if I run it without any constraints, separator lines still don't appear (despite the image and label fitting within the cell). I will play around some more with the constraints and see what I can do.

Comment: Try to make the scale of simulator to its physical size by pressing `cmd+1`, you may see your separator lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the constraints correctly

1- For the stackView give it leading , trailing ,top,bottom to container

2- For the imageview inside the cell give it leading

3- Either implement `heightForRowAt` and return a height , or set top & bottom constraints to the label and set automatic in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150    
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Try fixing these issues then see if the separator will show or not

//

I have created a demo check [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/37abvj5ejm8w3qz/TableCon.zip) , also make sure if you run in simulator to zoom or increase Scale as the separator disappear in small scales

//

[image]

Comment: I actually got rid of the StackView as It doesn't seem like I need it. I will reset the constraints and test out your suggestions.

Comment: So I actually cleared all  constraints within the tableview to check if it would work and oddly it doesn't seem to work even without constraints. I'm going to test out your suggestions.

Comment: Make sure don't run the app if you see any red arrow , you have to fix it this is the origin  of the problem

Comment: After clearing all constraints, I don't see any red arrows.

Comment: no you have to set them and not see any red arrows  Both together =D

Comment: Okay. So I was able to get rid of redlines and add constraints, by using "reset to suggested constraints." Despite this, separator lines don't seem to be appear. Off-topic, but if I'm choosing height and width that is smaller than the cell size for my imageView + label why am I getting redlines? I'm also getting redlines if I try to use "vertically in container."

Comment: right - it is **very unlikely** you need a stack view here

Comment: @Sh_Khan What version of Xcode is needed to run your project? I currently am using 9.2, and haven't upgraded as I don't want to upgrade my Phone iOS . I'm getting an "project incompatible" error when trying to open your project :(. I feel bad since you kind enough to create a demo.

Comment: @Sh_Khan EDIT: Okay despite the warning. I was able to copy your constraints exactly(or it seems) but the redlines are still not showing up. I updated the github project to reflect your constraints:  https://github.com/bigmit2011/TableView-TableView

Comment: @Moondra  zoomed in simulator or increased scale as i said in answer ????

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed that part. It seems to work =).

Answer (score 1):

The possible reason is that you are running in a very large screen simulator and you are scaling it down to small size, the simulator will sometimes compress the thin view, such as separator line, into nothingness, just scale up your simulator window larger or use real device then you will see it.

Checked your project and even though it have constraint error, it works fine and separator line show up normally.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could also mark you as the correct answer as well. Running it on my phone does show the thin red lines.